# Is there a way to add an onclick event to an ASP.NET Label server control?

Tags: asp.net, controls

I wanted to do something like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMyLabel" onclick="lblMyLabel_Click" runat="server">My Label</asp:Label>
```

I know that in Javascript I can do:

```
<span onclick="foo();">My Label</span>
```

So I'm wondering why I can't do that with a Label object.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use Attributes to add onclick client side callback.

I didn't know you can do this on span tags, but if it works you can add 'onclick' by `lblMyLabel.Attributes.Add("onclick", "foo();");`

But `foo();` would need to be a client side javascript function.

`System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label` does NOT have OnClick server event. You could look into using AJAX if you want server callback with example above.

You could also use `LinkButton` like other say. You can make it not look like a link by using CSS, if it is just that underline you are concerned about.

ASPX:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
    CssClass="imjusttext" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">
LinkButton
</asp:LinkButton>
```

CSS:

```
a.imjusttext{ color: #000000; text-decoration: none; }
a.imjusttext:hover { text-decoration: none; }
```

Answer (score 11):

Your question doesn't specify if you mean to raise the click event on the server (VB or c#) or the client (javascript.) If you're looking for a server-side event you should use a link button with css that makes the link appear as a label. You can then use the link button's server-side click event. If you're looking for a client-side click event - just type it into your server control markup 
 `asp:label id="MyLabel" runat="server" onclick="javascript:alert('hello');" Text="Click Me";`  
ASP.NET will emit additional attributes in the html markup that generates.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in code in the page_load eg:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
      lblMyLabel.Attributes.Add("onclick",
           "javascript:alert('ALERT ALERT!!!')");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want an onclick event, why don't you use a linkbutton, which has the `onclientclick` event:

```
<asp:linkbutton id="lblMyLink" onclientclick="lblMyLink_Click" runat="server">My Label</asp:linkbutton>
```

You can use CSS to make the link look like whatever you want

Comment: I didn't want it to look like a link and I didn't want to hack a link to look like plain text using CSS, but I guess that's what I have to do. :( Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can, but it's a client-side onclick handler, not server side.  It will complain about the attribute not being supported (or some such) but I think it renders correctly.  If you want to to a server-side handler, I think you'll need to do a LinkButton.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that's impossible. Label control emits `<span`> element which is “unclickable” on the server side. You would need to replace your Label control with a LinkButton.

Answer (score 1):

Another hack would be to use a hidden link or button with style="display:none;" and trigger the click on the server control from a javascript function in the span.

Something like this:

```
<asp:linkbutton id="lblMyLink" onClick="lblMyLink_Click" runat="server" style="display:none;">My Link</asp:linkbutton>
<span onclick="document.getElementById('lblMyLink').click();">My Label</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could always roll out your own control which produces a span, with the .net's standard postback javascript, but as stated earlier using a linklabel with a CSS class would be easier

Answer (score 0):

Just to chime in on this issue,
I used a label in my .aspx page that was only to be visible in my DataList Item template if there were child records in the dataset.

I added a onclick function to the label:

moreOptionsLabel.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("toggle_visibility('{0}')", div.ClientID));

in my .cs file. It will now control a div tag in the .aspx page to show or hide the records - because the onclick points to a client side javascript function. Notice the div.ClientID, that makes this workable in a datalist.

As noted above - the span tag does indeed become functional with "onclick". And since the label control is rendered as a span after the page request, using the Addtribute.Add("onclick".... does work.

The result is show/hide functionality of data with out doing a postback. If you use the LinkButton, or simlar controls  - the postback and page reload is unavoidable - unless you want to get into some Ajax stuff.

NOTE: the span tag won't look clickable unless you style it with an underline and hand cursor.

Credit to this idea comes from Will Asrari over at http://www.willasrari.com/blog/display-nested-repeaters-and-gridviews-asynchronously/000292.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class object that inherits from the label and onclick event handler which will be a method by yourslef and use your object as a custom label.