# Radio button text on the right side

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using radio buttons in my application is there any possible way to shift the text from the left side to right side

Comment: Have you tried like the way I posted the answer?

Comment: yes the problem is When I click the content the button will not get selected

Comment: Are you using plain HTML?
Make sure the label references the id of the radio button. Then the clicking on label will select the radio button.

<input type="radio" id="radButton" /><label for="radButton">Some text on the right</label>

Comment: @Mathew Paul if you want to achieve like clicking on content, write some code to select radio button in the click event of label.

Comment: @kalyan Yes Thanks Kalyan I am going to do something like that

Comment: @MathewPaul refer to the this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181097/is-there-a-way-to-add-an-onclick-event-to-an-asp-net-label-server-control to get the Onclick event for a label

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `TextAlign` property to "Right" on the list it belongs to.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.textalign.aspx

Example (use a standard WebApplication in VS and include the following in default.aspx):

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id="RadioButtonList1"
     RepeatDirection="Vertical" 
     RepeatLayout="Table"  
     TextAlign="Right"  
     runat="server">

    <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 5</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 6</asp:ListItem>

</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

[image: The Result]

The result for setting TextAlign to Left is:

[image]

Comment: @AlexDuggleby, but it will not change the radiobutton text from left to right side of the control

Comment: Have to disagree, see expanded answer. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @AlexDuggleby, he needs a functionality like "Text(righttothat)Radiocontrol" and not "Radiocontrol(lefttocontrol)Text"

Comment: I tried with the above code again its displaying the text on the left hand side of the radiobutton

Comment: Ok, so set the TextAlign to Left, see answer.

Comment: @MathewPaul Ok, please post your ASPX code/snippet, because if you paste that code into a clean VS project the result is as shown in the image. I'll try to help if I can see more of the code. Maybe there some JS/CSS getting in the way?

Comment: @Alex When I give TextAlign to either Left or Right it is showing on the Left hand side of the Radio button

Comment: @Alex just now did it in a fresh page and found your answer as valid thanks for the answer I think there is some problem in the css file I will check it out Thanks once again

Comment: @AlexDuggleby, sorry for misunderstanding your code part. Its perfectly working. I am wrong actually.