# not able to align radiobuttonlist

Tags: html, css, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I am not able to align radiobutton list to left of label above.
Here is code

```
  <div style="border-radius: 10px;">
        <div style="margin-bottom: 10px"></div>
        <asp:Panel ID="panel" runat="server">
            <div style="padding-left: 10px" >
                <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="Select criteria" />
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radio" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="radio_SelectedIndexChanged" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"   />
                <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="Value"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="ScoreMethodLabel" runat="server" Text="Score"></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="dropscore" runat="server" />&nbsp;
            </div>

        </asp:Panel>
        <br/>
    </div>
```

Here is output i see

[image]

you see the option button is not aligned exaxctly below text called "Select criteria"

Comment: right click the radio button, *inspect element* (on chrome atleast) and hover over the element in the inspector panel - then check if the element shows any orange / purple coloring, if this is true orange means margin and purple means padding. You can then go ahead and reset that in your CSS

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand i see Orange color but even if i added margin its not aligning

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand when i open up html using F12. Then its rendered as input type=radio and when i add margin:0 then it Works. But not when i directly add property margin:0 on asp:radiobuttonlist

Comment: Here is a similar question on so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767812/radio-button-text-on-the-right-side

Comment: @शेखर thats not what i want. I want to align option button to left of label above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to `margin:0`

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   }

input[type=radio] {
        margin: 0;
   }
```

Comment: doesnt make differenc

Comment: i added like this <asp:RadioButtonList ID="SelectCriteriaList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectCriteriaList_SelectedIndexChanged" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" style ="margin:0"   />

Comment: doesnt make difference. But when i open up html using F12. Then its rendered as input type=radio and when i add margin:0 then it Works. But not when i directly add property margin:0 on asp:radiobuttonlist

Comment: i also added Your code in my style sheet but doesnt change anything

Comment: remember that repeatdirection is set to horiziontal on my radionbuttonlist .. does that make any difference.

Comment: add this style to your stylesheet  *{margin:0;}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99933/discussion-between-happy-and-lalji-tadhani).