# Label server side click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I have a label control and and JavaScript function `callme()` as follows. When a click on <kbd>Press label</kbd>, it works.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblpress" runat="server" onclick="callme()" Text="Press"></asp:Label>
```

I want to click this label client side event,  programatically from server side event. How can I do it?

Comment: Register it as start-up script.

Comment: This artical will help you onclick event to Lable server side


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181097/is-there-a-way-to-add-an-onclick-event-to-an-asp-net-label-server-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Attributes collection property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes.aspx)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    lblpress.Attributes.Add("onclick", "'callme()'");

    //if the attribute already exist, you can change it this way
    lblpress.Attributes["onclick"] = "'callme()'";
}
```

> The Attributes collection contains a collection of all attributes
>   declared in the opening tag of a Web server control. This allows you
>   to programmatically control the attributes associated with a Web
>   server control. You can add attributes to the collection or remove
>   attributes from the collection

Comment: Thank for reply,i don't want to add attribute ,just want to fire click event .

Comment: Go with @BehnamEsmaili's answer

Comment: lblpress.Attributes["onclick"] = "'callme()'";  make  exactly what i want.It fire an client side event .Thank y so much

Answer (score 0):

you can use RegisterClientScriptBlock for doing this.

```
    String csName = "LabelClickScript";    
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;   
    StringBuilder csText = new StringBuilder();
    csText.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> function DoClick() {");
    csText.Append("alert('Text from client script.')

                    } 
                    DoClick();
                  </");
    csText.Append("script>");
    cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), csName, csText.ToString());
```

Comment: when i try this , the whole page become refresh .

Comment: I don't understand why you want to click a label from server side when you can call the JavaScript function directly? any explanation?

Comment: actually i facing jquery problem .Some Control use jquery and this control need to use updatepanel.So, when i fire server side event,the controls of jquery effect dissaper.At the side of jquery ,also try with "live" ,but it only work for control event,not for pre define jquery function.So i want to call jquery function at the server side.I'm trying any way.Label click is one of my test.May be so confuse my writing..

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use proper controls like ,link button or Anchor in HTML