# How to execute a js function onclick of RibbonBarButton

Tags: javascript, telerik-radribbonbar

I am trying to execute a js fuction onclick of RibbonBarButton. But RibbonBarButton dosn't have a onclientclick. How can i do this?

```
    function appendRow() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('myTable');
    row = tbl.insertRow(tbl.rows.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
      var insertcell = (row.insertCell(i), i, 'row');
    }
}
```

MarkUp:

```
<telerik:RibbonBarSplitButton Size="Medium">
    <Buttons>
       <telerik:RibbonBarButton Text="Add Row" runat="server" ID="btnAppendRow" />
       <telerik:RibbonBarButton Text="Add Column" runat="server" ID="btnaddCol" /> 
    </Buttons>
</telerik:RibbonBarSplitButton>
```

I tried this but not working:

```
$("").click(function(){
    appendRow();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a client-side event, just type it into your server control tag: https://stackoverflow.com/a/181118/5581893

Basically, you can change your first button this way:

From:

```
<telerik:RibbonBarButton Text="Add Row" runat="server" ID="btnAppendRow" />
```

To:

```
<telerik:RibbonBarButton Text="Add Row" runat="server" ID="btnAppendRow" 
onclick="appendRow();"/>
```